Surface area of a plane bounded by cylinder
I have to find the surface area of the plane $x + 2y + 2z = 12$ cut off by $x = 0$, $y = 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 16$
The solution I am following does this:
$$A = \int\int\sqrt{1+z_{x}^2 + z_y^2}dxdy$$
The integral taken over the projected area on the $xy$ plane. Please help me understand why this gives the right answer.
